# Modify threshold of Pull-to-Refresh on React-Native

Tags: reactjs, react-native

Is there any way I can change the threshold of Pull-to-Refresh on FlatList?

Seems like [syrusakbary/react-native-refresher](https://github.com/syrusakbary/react-native-refresher#props) have a threshold prop, but I wanted to know if there are any way to modify without using external library.

added:
Maybe I wasn't clear enough. I want to set `threshold` value somewhere to change the distance between start of pull-down action and where the re-loading starts.

What I want to achieve is a shorter distance for reload to trigger, since it seems too long by default.

I know there is no option for `FlatList` to change that distance, but I want to know if there is other way to solve this problem.

Comment: It's not a perfect solution, but you can try it. `onEndReachedThreshold`